# Why Cassandra is used for Kong Api Gateway

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, system-design, kong, nosql

Kong uses Cassandra or Postgres. Cassandra is know for write heavy application.I don't see Kong api gateway is that much write heavy,also none of table uses Cassandra one of the important feature partition key. My doubt is why Cassandra is used for Kong,is there any specific reason? Can't we acheive this using RDBMS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the Kong FAQ at https://getkong.org/about/faq/#which-datastores-are-supported

Postgresql

> It is a good candidate if the setup you are aiming at is not distributed

Cassandra

> Kong can use Cassandra as its primary datastore if you are aiming at a
>   distributed, high-availability Kong setup. The two main reasons why
>   one would chose Cassandra as Kong's datastore are: - An ease to create
>   a distributed setup (ideal for multi-region). - Ease to scale